# Making some setting in the remote PC so that its IP address can be traced

Tags: ip, remote-access

I have a shared PC at a remote place on LAN. I usually work on that using remote Desktop connection. But sometimes the IP address of the pc gets changed when someone accidentally or intentionally unplug and plug the Ethernet cable. In that case, it is required to reach the PC physically to get the new IP which sometimes is inconvenient for me.

Is there any setting that I can make on the PC so that I can find the new IP address from some other machine? The OS installed is Ubuntu on the shared computer and I have root access to it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use dynamic dns install on your remote pc.

and control you pc by dns or ping your dns to get the ip address.

here is  a chinese version app.

http://www.oray.com/peanuthull/download.php